# Do you write a function that outputs a vector as a vector?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, notation, vectors

If I have a function that maps from $\mathbb{R}^n$ to $\mathbb{R}^m$ and thus returns a vector, and I want to call it f, do I write it as $f(\vec{x})$ or $\vec{f}(\vec{x})$?

Comment: The former is correct, notation could also be $f(\textbf{x})$

Comment: @BenjaminMoss which notation is preferred for vectors, bold or arrow over it? I've seen both in common use, is it just a cultural thing?

Comment: I generally like bold because it looks a bit "cleaner," but its all a matter of preference

Comment: It isn't necessary that it have any special notation added.  A plain $x$ is fine too.  Merely saying $f~:~\Bbb R^n\to \Bbb R^m$ is enough to imply what sort of object the $x$ in $f(x)$ is, namely an element of $\Bbb R^n$.

Comment: Then arrow notation seems to be preferred by physicists and engineers and the bold by mathematicians.  Neither is "more correct" so long as your audience understands what you are trying to communicate.

Comment: @BenjaminMoss I would rather say that the latter is correct, because the value of the function is a vector, and that a ('cleaner') notation would be with both $f$ and $x$ bold.

Comment: @Karlo that works as well, I definitely like that notation more than my initial format

Comment: @Karlo $f$ is not itself a vector of any of the mentioned vector spaces, it is a function between vector spaces and is thus formally a subset of $\Bbb R^n\times \Bbb R^m$, not an element of.  As such, I would disagree with the arrow being over the $f$ exclusively if you were trying to mimic patterns, going instead for $\overrightarrow{f(\overrightarrow{x})}$... which to me seems overkill.  As I already tried to allude to though, there is no need for set conventions here and you can notate however you like. The context is more important than the symbols and notation used in letting us interpret

Comment: In more advanced mathematics one would just write $f (x) $ with no arrows or boldface. The reader is then assumed to be able to remember that it's codomain is $\mathbb R^m $.

Answer (score 0):

When you write the function in one of the two equivalent ways—

$$\mathbf{f}(\mathbf{x})=\vec{f}(\vec{x})$$

—you are unequivocally communicating that the function takes vectors as its inputs and returns vectors as its outputs. I don’t think that anyone would be under the impression that the function can also map scalars to vectors, but I believe you probably clear that up when you say $\mathbf{f}:\Bbb{R}^m\to\Bbb{R}^n$.